# How do we make it so that @media only max-width doesn't apply to larger screens?

Tags: html, css

How do I make it so 'margin: 0 auto;' is only applying to mobile devices? For whatever reason, it's applying it to desktops and ipads too.

```
   @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
     #scrollToTopBtn{
       display: none !important;
     }
   }

   @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
     .card-buttons{
       margin: 0 auto;
     }
   }
```

the margin - auto; to center a buttons in a div is being applied to ipad/desktop sizes.

Comment: Your second style block should only be applied to devices / browser windows that are less than or equal to 768px wide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `min-width` and `max-width` in `@media()` queries to more specify your devices screen.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 767px)  {
  //Put your CSS here for 200px to 767px width devices (cover all mobile portrait width //
}
```